# Passing allocatable character(:) slices with negative stride segfaults GFortran, Why?

Tags: fortran

Why does this Fortran program segfault? Is it the compiler, or have I violated the standard - and if so, how?

```
! gfortran -fcheck=all arrays10.f90 && ./a
! GNU Fortran (GCC) 11.4.0
program arrays10
    implicit none

    ! Non-allocatable variables don't trigger the segfault.
    !integer :: a(3)
    !character(5) :: b(3)

    integer, allocatable :: a(:)
    character(:), allocatable :: b(:)

    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [ character(5) :: "one", "two", "three"]

    print *, "Test integer array"
    print *, "loc: ", loc(a)
    call test01(a)
    call test01(a(size(a):1:-1))
    print *

    print *, "Test character(*) (:)"
    print *, "loc: ", loc(b)
    call test02(b)
    ! Only segfaults with negative stride
    call test02(b(size(b):1:-1))
    print *

    print *, "Test character(*) (*)"
    print *, "loc: ", loc(b)
    call test03(b)
    ! Only segfaults with negative stride
    call test03(b(size(b):1:-1))
    print *

    contains

    subroutine test01(a)
        ! no segfault

        ! Requires contiguous memory, creates temporary array
        !integer, intent(in) :: a(3)

        ! Inherits stride, no temporary array
        integer, intent(in) :: a(:)

        integer i

        print *, "testing: ", rank(a), size(a)
        ! But loc() apparently has layout requirements
        ! temporary array created
        print *, loc(a)
        do i = 1, size(a)
            print *, a(i)
        end do
        print *
    end subroutine test01

    subroutine test02(a)
        ! A program that triggers:
        ! Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

        ! Forces allocatable argument, not useful
        !character(:), allocatable, intent(in) :: a(:)

        ! These both should force a temporary array, but I don't see the warning.
        ! That's because the segfault is triggered around here (if uncommented).
        !character(*), intent(in) :: a(3)
        !character(5), intent(in) :: a(3)

        ! No temporary array should be created.
        character(*), intent(in) :: a(:)

        integer i

        print *, "testing: ", rank(a), size(a), len(a(1))
        ! Once again, forcing a temporary array triggers the same segfault
        !print *, loc(a)
        ! Iterating in the original order still triggers a segfault.
        !do i = size(a), 1, -1
        do i = 1, size(a)
            ! segfault here (on first iteration): invalid memory reference
            print *, "          ", a(i)
        end do
        print *
    end subroutine test02

    subroutine test03(a)
        ! Same results as test02

        ! For both, segfault triggered around here
        character(*), intent(in) :: a(*)
        !character(*), intent(in) :: a(1)

        print *, "testing: ", rank(a), size(a(:3)), len(a(1))
        print *, loc(a)
        print *
    end subroutine test03

end program arrays10
```

Comment: It does not crash for me. Please tell us the compiler version and the operating system.

Comment: Ifx with -check does give some wrong access, but the location given by the sanitizer does not make sense. I think that that compiler is not mature, despite their deprecation of ifort.

Comment: doesn't crash either for me on https://godbolt.org/z/631es3rqo , whatever the version of gfortran...

Comment: GNU Fortran (GCC) 11.4.0 as `gfortran -fcheck=all arrays10.f90` on Cygwin 3.4.7-1.x86_64.

Comment: @PierU I didn't know godbolt offered fortran. I should check next time before asking such a question.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I'm curious how you would check this as I didn't find gdb useful: (1) Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?) (But it captured the relevant frame) (2) in relevant frame: `info addr a` gives "Symbol "a" is a complex DWARF expression: 0: DW_OP_fbreg 8; 2: DW_OP_deref .". Is this helpful? I'm not sure what it is, perhaps a pointer on a register? *edit*: this was when compiled with "-fcheck=all -ggdb -O0".

Comment: @PierU But according to the output from goldbolt.org, even though `call test02(b(size(b):1:-1))` doesn't segfault it does output (what I assume is) junk memory rather than the reversed array. @VladimirFГероямслава, is your output correct?

Comment: Yes, for gfortran the results are incorrect and valgrind complains of "Condiitonal jumps depends on uninitialized values". For Intel the arrays is reversed. Peculiarly, the garbage is always the same and the first element printed is "one". I think you should report it to the developers at their bugzilla.

Comment: Ah yes, it messes up the temporary arrays! I was only focused on the segfault... I think this code is valid Fortran, and it looks like a gfortran bug to me

Comment: Thanks! I filed a bug report with the GCC/GFortran bugzilla.